# Random sample from another table's column

Tags: arrays, sas, simulation

I am trying to figure out how to populate a "fake" column by choosing randomly from another table column.
So far this was easy using an array and the `rantbl()` function as there were not a lot of modalities.

```
data want;
set have;

array values[2] $10 _temporary_ ('NO','YES');
value=values[rantbl(0,0.5,0.5)];

array start_dates[4] _temporary_ (1735689600,1780358400,1798848000,1798848000);
START_DATE=start_dates[rantbl(0,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25)];

format START_DATE datetime20.;
run;
```

However, my question is what happens if there are, for example, more than 150 modalities in the other table? Hence, is there a way to put into an array all the modalities that are in another table ? Or better, to populate the new "fake" column with modalities from another table's column with regards to the modalities's distribution in the other table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but here's how I interpret your request and how I would solve it.

You have a table `one`. You want to create a new data set `want` with an additional column. This column should have values that are sampled from a pool of values given in yet another data set `two` in column `y`. You want too simulate the new column in the `want` data set according to the distribution of `y` in the `two` data set.

So, in the example below, there should be a .5 change of simulating y = 3 and .25 for 1 and 2 respectively.

I think the way to go is not using arrays at all. See if this helps you.

```
data one;
   do x = 1 to 1e4;
      output;
   end;
run;

data two;
input y;
datalines;
1
2
3
3
;

data want;
   set one;
   p = ceil(rand('uniform')*n);
   set two(keep = y) nobs = n point = p;
run;
```

To verify that the new column resembles the distribution from the `two` data set:

```
proc freq data = want;
   tables y / nocum;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a dozen *good* ways to do this, which one being ideal depending on various details of your data - in particular, how performance sensitive this is.

The most SASsy way to do this, I would say, is to use [PROC SURVEYSELECT](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.4&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_surveyselect_syntax01.htm&locale=en#).  This generates a random sample of the size you want, and then merges it on.  It is not the *fastest* way, but it is very easy to understand and is fast-ish as long as you aren't talking humungous data sizes.

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.cars nobs=nobs_cars;
  call symputx('nobs_cars',nobs_Cars);
  stop;
run;

proc surveyselect data=sashelp.class sampsize=&nobs_Cars out=names(keep=name) 
                  seed=7 method=urs outhits outorder=random;
run;

data want;
  merge sashelp.cars names;
run;
```

In this example, we are taking the dataset `sashelp.cars`, and appending an owner's name to each car, which we choose at random from the dataset `sashelp.class`.

What we're doing here is first determining how many records we need - the number of observations in the to-be-merged-to dataset.  This step can be skipped if you know that already, but it takes basically zero time no matter what the dataset size.

Second, we use `proc surveyselect` to generate the random list.  We use `method=urs` to ask for simple random sampling with replacement, meaning we take 428 (in this case) separate pulls, each time every row being equally likely to be chosen.  We use `outhits` and `outorder=random` to get a dataset with one row per desired output dataset row and in a random order (without `outhits` it gives one row per input dataset row, and a number of times sampled variable, and without `outrandom` it gives them in sorted order).  `sampsize` is used with our created macro variable that stores the number of observations in the eventual output dataset.

Third, we do a side by side merge (with no `by` statement, intentionally).  Please note that in some installations, `options mergenoby` is set to give a warning or error for this particular usage; if so you may need to do this slightly differently, though it is easy to do so using two `set` statements (`set sashelp.cars; set names;`) to achieve the identical results.